# Pre-Whitening results not conducive to white noise property

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, autocorrelation, stationarity

I have these two time series(df_errror,df_booking) (both are non-stationary, seasonal) that I want to prewhiten and then find cross correlation:

[image]
[image]

I used this code for auto_arima for df_booking:

```
ar1model = auto.arima(

 df_booking['sum'],d = 1,
 D = 1,
 max.p = 5,
 max.q = 5,
 max.P = 3,
 max.Q = 3,
 max.D = 3,
 max.d=3,
 max.order = 5,
 start.p = 1,
 start.q = 1,
 start.P = 1,
 start.Q = 1,
 seasonal=TRUE,
 stationary=TRUE
 )
```

This yields a results of ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,1,0)[12] as the best order with no coefficients. My results change significantly if change truth values of seasonal,stationary hyperparameter.

I then save the residuals.

```
pwx=ar1model$residuals
pwy = residuals(Arima(df_error_plot['Error_Percent'], model = ar1model))
```

Then I check the residuals for statonarity:

```
adf.test(pwx,k=12)
adf.test(pwy,k=12)
```

BUT they are NOT below 0.38,0.34. Which means my residuals are not stationary( requirement for white noise /pre-whitening)

While the acf and pacf plots of the residuals show auto-correlation at only 0 lag and all below confidence intervals(which is I guess what is required for white noise):

```
 acf(pwx,lag=30)
 acf(pwy,lag=30)
```

I tried to transform the df_booking['sum'] to log and cube_root to see if that changes the results for adf.test() but it doesn't .

I have a few questions regarding it:

1. Does passing transformed data in auto.arima() has any effect on the results
2. Why does the value of k make such any effect, because when I change it 0 I do get the results of stationarity but they are 0.01 regardless of any transformed data.
3. Why are the residuals showing no-autocorrelation but not stationarity
4. How are my values changing so much when I change seasonal and stationary hyperparameter?
5. Is the approach to prewhiten correct?

Comment: Could the problems be due to the function, and therefore R, and thus better asked in https://stackoverflow.com/?